# Debugging of module in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

How to debug the modules in Linux? As their will be no executable file for the modules? What does ELF will do ? Only the Makefile i have complied and given me object file and various other files.

Comment: Often, there are debug versions of libraries etc.

Comment: `printk` and its variants are your friend (assuming you mean Linux kernel modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As their will be no executable file for the modules?

There is no executable (like `a.out`), but there is kernel object file `*.ko`. Kernel object files are *added to* or *removed from* the kernel via `insmod` and `rmmod`.

So at minimum, you need to be able to do the following to debug a kernel module:

- Locate the module itself (`*.c` file and corresponding `*.ko` kernel object).
- Add (a lot of) `printk`
- Rebuild the kernel.
- `rmmod` the old module, `insmod` the new version.
- Watch out debug logs, normally via `dmesg`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods for debugging by printing (i.e printk),watching,querying
[Refer](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch04.html) to understand different debugging methods for module. Obvious method is we can use printk and after inserting (`insmod`) and removing (`rmmod`) module and that message can be seen in kernel buffer using `$dmesg`